# Create stacked 2d matrix along z axis with surf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

The following figure is just a representation of a 2d array with surf. I would like to create a similar figure with 10 of these 2d arrays stacked on top of each other with some kind of offset along the z axis.

```
figure();
surf(X);
colormap(hsv);
shading interp;
campos([-70 -150 80]);
grid on;
set(gcf,'color','w');
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `surf` several times with `hold on`, applying a gradually increasing offset.

By **default** (1-input version of `surf`), the offset will affect the colors shown for each surface. Here's an example with three 2D arrays. Note that peak-to-peak amplitude is different for each one.

```
x{1} = .2*peaks(30);
x{2} = .4*peaks(30);
x{3} = .8*peaks(30); % cell array containing three 2D arrays
offset = 7; % desired offset
hold on
for k = 1:numel(x)
    surf(x{k} + offset*(k-1))
end
campos([-100 -170 90])
grid on
```

[image]

To prevent offset from affecting color, i.e. **achieve consistent color for all surfaces**, use the 2- or 4-input version of `surf` to separately specify height and color:

```
x{1} = .2*peaks(30);
x{2} = .4*peaks(30);
x{3} = .8*peaks(30);
offset = 7;
hold on
for k = 1:numel(x)
    surf(x{k} + offset*(k-1), x{k}) % Only this line has been changed
end
campos([-100 -170 90])
grid on
```

[image]

To generate **stacked planes** (no height variations) with color depending on value: modify the input arguments as follows:

```
x{1} = .2*peaks(30);
x{2} = .4*peaks(30);
x{3} = .8*peaks(30);
offset = 7;
hold on
for k = 1:numel(x)
    surf(repmat(offset*(k-1), size(x{k})), x{k}) % Only this line has been changed
end
campos([-100 -170 90])
grid on
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Yeah, it does affect the colors shown for each surface. Since I'm curious I wanted to ask if it's also possible to use 'pcolor' instead of surf in this case? I would loose the elevations but that's okay.

Comment: @ShaibalAhmed Good question. It can't be done with `pcolor` AFAIK, but it can with `surf`, using two different input arguments for specifying height and color. This is can also be applied to the original (non-flat) surfaces to make their colors independent of offset. See edited answer